# proper logic behind Data Grid View C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I have been struggling with a dataviewgrid control for about a week now with no success.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to check for null values in cell[0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXWGn.png),[2] and not allow the user to leave the row until they meet the condition of not being null.  I have tried many different events from cell validation to row validation and row leave, enter etc... My problem is that if the user lets say adds the first name and then leaves the row I can verify the data was not entered into the other two fields that I require. However, it still allows them to leave the row before completing the entry. I need some logic on how the best way to go about checking this and not allowing the user to input null values.  Here is a screen shot and some of my code that I have tried thus far.

[image]

as it is right now there control is read only and I have a button to create a new entry.  I would much rather have the user be able to freely edit, remove and add entry's as they see fit.

```
        private void datagridCustomers_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        int lastRow = datagridCustomers.Rows.Count - 1;

        datagridCustomers.ClearSelection();

        if (datagridCustomers.Rows[lastRow].Cells[0].Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value can't be null.");
            datagridCustomers.ClearSelection();
            datagridCustomers.Rows[lastRow].Cells[0].Selected = true;
            datagridCustomers.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first handling the cell validating event, checking the `EditedFormattedValue` for each of the "Required" cells of that row. The cells that are `null` will have an `EditedFormattedValue` of `string.Empty`.

When one of the indicated cells is empty, we can set `e.Cancel = true` and manually set the empty cell as the `CurrentCell`.

```
public void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex < 3)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.dataGridView1[col, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value can't be null.");
                e.Cancel = true;

                this.dataGridView1.CellValidating -= dataGridView1_CellValidating;
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[col, e.RowIndex];
                this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                this.dataGridView1.CellValidating += dataGridView1_CellValidating;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because we set `e.Cancel = true` we need to also add the following method to skip this validation on `Form.Closing`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (((m.WParam.ToInt64() & 0xffff) & 0xfff0))
    {
        case 0xf060:
            this.dataGridView1.CausesValidation = false;
            break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Learned a few different things from this and this seems to work great. However, can you please explain why you are describing from the event and then resubscribing? Not sure I understand why that is happening.

Comment: @Timg Sure. I describe/resubscribe to the event because of the line setting the `CurrentCell`.  Without doing so, setting the current cell recalls the `CellValidating` event, which - again finds the `null` cell, resets the `CurrentCell`, and triggers the same cycle - ending in a Stack Overflow.